# Critical Error: This server does not appear to have Microsoft XML 4.0 Core Services installed. Object required

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I saw this when I run the website project:

> Critical Error:  This server does not appear to have Microsoft XML 4.0
>   Core Services installed. Object required

I researched it and downloaded MSXML 4.0 Service Pack 3 (Microsoft XML Core Services) (I tried to install the first one, then run the website, still saw the error, even after I restarted my web browser and computer.)and it's Pack 2 version after I tried the Pack 3.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I uninstalled the IIS URL Rewrite Module 2, it solved this problem.....